# How do I get Pidgin connected to ICQ again?

Tags: pidgin

A few days ago Pidgin gave me this error message from ICQ:

```
Received unexpected response from https://api.oscar.aol.com/aim/startOSCARSession: Ok
```

Now it won't connect. I searched in Google and several sites said this was a temporary problem that's happened before. However, it's been many days now and ICQ still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Start Pidgin and go into Edit Account (Accounts -> your account name -> Edit Account), then change to the Advanced tab and uncheck "Use clientLogin". If you still can't login, try unchecking "Use SSL" too (although that may not be recommended).

Hope it works for you!

Comment: "Use clientLogin" worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mail.ru Group (owner of ICQ network since July2010), blocked access from non-native clients. They just changed ICQ protocol as many times ago. Maybe, Pidgin developers correct this soon :) For now, try update from Pidgin PPA ([ppa:pidgin-developers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ppa))

PS. Not all countries are banned (based on IP)

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug 2011 (pidgin 2.7.11, package version 1:2.7.11-1ubuntu2) the following settings work:

- Server: slogin.oscar.aol.com
- Port: 5190
- Use encryption if available
- Use clientLogin ticked

Unfortunately forcing encryption doesn't seem to work (which makes me suspect no encryption is used in the end).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, if you're trying to get ICQ working in Pidgin, I found that the only way to connect was with a new plugin: https://github.com/EionRobb/icyque

The link to the latest builds was broken for me, but I was able to successfully compile it myself, and copy the `.so` file to ~/.purple/plugins/.

This was on Linux Mint. YMMV with other operating systems.

Comment: The only solution that works in Out, 2021. Install libpurple-dev and libjson-glib-dev to compile.